# How to use React Hooks with video.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using video.js in React. I try to migrate to React Hooks.

My React version is 16.8.3

This is original working code:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import videojs from 'video.js';

class VideoPlayer extends PureComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { videoSrc } = this.props;
    const { playerRef } = this.refs;

    this.player = videojs(playerRef, { autoplay: true, muted: true }, () => {
      this.player.src(videoSrc);
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.player) this.player.dispose()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div data-vjs-player>
        <video ref="playerRef" className="video-js vjs-16-9" playsInline />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

After adding React Hooks

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import videojs from 'video.js';

function VideoPlayer(props) {
  const { videoSrc } = props;
  const playerRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const player = videojs(playerRef.current, { autoplay: true, muted: true }, () => {
      player.src(videoSrc);
    });

    return () => {
      player.dispose();
    };
  });

  return (
    <div data-vjs-player>
      <video ref="playerRef" className="video-js vjs-16-9" playsInline />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I got the error

> Invariant Violation: Function components cannot have refs. Did you
>   mean to use React.forwardRef()?

But I am using React Hooks `useRef` instead of `refs` actually. Any guide will be helpful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are passing a string to the video element's `ref` prop. Give it the `playerRef` variable instead.

You can also give `useEffect` an empty array as second argument as you only want to run the effect after the initial render.

```
function VideoPlayer(props) {
  const { videoSrc } = props;
  const playerRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const player = videojs(playerRef.current, { autoplay: true, muted: true }, () => {
      player.src(videoSrc);
    });

    return () => {
      player.dispose();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div data-vjs-player>
      <video ref={playerRef} className="video-js vjs-16-9" playsInline />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey I am getting **TypeError: The element or ID supplied is not valid. (videojs)** error